# Matlab matrix attribution according to other matrix value

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have one matrix *data* like that:

```
   1      2    3  

1: 1.0    2.0  5.0 
2: 2.0    2.0  5.0              
3: 4.0    0    5.0
```

And another matrix *test* like this:

```
   1      2    3  

1: 3.0    0     0 
2: 0      5.0   0              
3: 0      0    3.0
```

**The problem:** set data so that: data(i,j) = 0 when test(i,j) == 0

My code for that:

```
for i=1:N
        for j=1:M
                if test(i,j) == 0
                        data(i,j) = 0;
                end 
        end 
end
```

**Question:** Is there a loop-free way to do this/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Try this

```
 data(find(test==0)) = 0;
```

or as @Peter says in comment below, this simpler form will suffice

```
 data(test==0) = 0;
```

Comment: You don't even need the `find`.  `data(test==0) = 0` will do as well